# PHP execute shell command and return full output

Tags: php, linux, shell

I'm having trouble getting the full output from a shell command returned to a PHP script.

If i run this command in the terminal:

`cd /home/moodledata; sh gam-create.sh "12345" "Test" "Mc Person"`

Then I get the following as output in the terminal:

`Creating account for 654321@ourdomain.ac.uk
Error 409: Entity already exists. - duplicate`

However, if I run that through a PHP script:

```
<?php
$u = "Test";
$s = "Mc Person";
$u = "654321";

exec("cd /home/moodledata; sh gam-create.sh \"$u\" \"$f\" \"$s\"", $retval);
var_dump($retval);
```

I only get the following for the returned output:

```
array(1){
  [0] => string(49) "Creating account for 654321@ourdomain.ac.uk"
}
```

I don't get the error message.

I've played around with using different functions, such as shell_exec() passthru() and system() but can't see to get this full output to be returned to the PHP script.

Could anyone advise as to where I'm going wrong?

Cheers.

Comment: You really tried to use `passthru` and didn't get the whole output back? Really?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, nevermind, I worked it out now. I needed to append `2>&1` to the command